# Native elegant way of do() function of "Then" framework

Tags: swift

I have encounter a framework called "Then" syntactic sugar for Swift initializers and liked the way `do` function seems like clear to me. Can i use some function or extension to get rid of my instance repeating itself without using "Then" ?

```
let tableView = UITableView()

tableView.do {
        $0.backgroundView = UIView()
        $0.backgroundView?.isHidden = true
        $0.backgroundColor = .white
        $0.register(UserListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: UserListCell.self))
    }
```

---

my intend is something like this:

```
let tableView = UITableView()
tableView.extension {
$0.backgroundView = UIView()
$0.backgroundView?.isHidden = true
$0.backgroundColor = .white
$0.register(UserListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: UserListCell.self))
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example using pseudo code how it would be more "shortly and clear"?

Comment: Trailing closure syntax doesn’t require the parentheses `()`

Comment: I just thought repeating tableView for all line looks not clear, if you guys suggest that using for every line is better approach it is ok to me. @LeoDabus

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You just want to do the same as the framework without it?

Comment: @LeoDabus trying to explain my best, yeah exactly if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a protocol that requires an empty initializer and constrain NSObject to it. Then you can create a custom initializer that take the tasks:

```
public protocol AnyProtocol {
    init()
}
```

---

```
extension NSObject: AnyProtocol { }
```

---

```
public extension AnyProtocol {
    init(_ tasks: (inout Self) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        self.init()
        try tasks(&self)
    }
}
```

---

```
let tableView = UITableView {
    $0.backgroundView = UIView()
    $0.backgroundView?.isHidden = true
    $0.backgroundColor = .red
}

tableView.backgroundColor // r 1.0 g 0.0 b 0.0 a 1.0
```

---

Or if you prefer it as a method:

```
public extension AnyProtocol {
    func batch(_ tasks: (Self) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        try tasks(self)
    }
}
tableView.batch {
    $0.isHidden = true
    $0.backgroundColor = .blue
}
tableView.isHidden         // true
tableView.backgroundColor  // r 0.0 g 0.0 b 1.0 a 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But the compiler is kind of dumb about this at the moment, so you'll need to manually "disambiguate" at call site, if you want all the overloads.

```swift
@Wrapped private var tableView = UITableView()
```

```swift
$tableView() { tableView -> Void in
  tableView.backgroundView = UIView()
  tableView.backgroundView?.isHidden = true
  tableView.backgroundColor = .white
  tableView.register(UserListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: UserListCell.self))
}
```

(The first line should look like this, allowing you to use $0.)

`$tableView {`

```swift
/// An affordance for adding extensions to every type.
@propertyWrapper public struct Wrapped<Value> {
  public var wrappedValue: Value
  public var projectedValue: Self { self }

  public init(wrappedValue: Value) {
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
  }
}

public extension Wrapped where Value: AnyObject {
  func callAsFunction(
    transform: (Value) throws -> Void
  ) rethrows {
    try transform(wrappedValue)
  }
}

public extension Wrapped {
  init(_ wrappedValue: Value) {
    self.init(wrappedValue: wrappedValue)
  }

  func callAsFunction(
    transform: (Value) throws -> Value
  ) rethrows -> Value {
    try transform(wrappedValue)
  }

  mutating func callAsFunction(
    transform: (inout Value) throws -> Void
  ) rethrows {
    try transform(&wrappedValue)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is kind of iceberg :) But thanks i liked your approach