# How do I format a date string into something like Jan 15th 2022?

Tags: swift

I'm using the Nasa API. It returns dates in raw string format: **"date": "2022-01-15"** (YYYY-MM-DD)

How do I format it to something like **Jan 15th, 2022** using `DateFormatter` and display it in a SwiftUI Text View?

```
private var dateFormatter = DateFormatter().configure {
    $0.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $0.dateStyle = .medium
    $0.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
    $0.locale = .current
    $0.timeStyle = .medium
}

private var formattedDate: String {
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: apod.date) else { return "No date" }
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

// Call site
Text(formattedDate)
```

It gives me "No date" on all items

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate formatter did the trick

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter().configure {
    $0.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
}

var dateFormatterOutput = DateFormatter().configure {
    $0.dateStyle = .full
}

private var formattedDate: String {
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: apod.date) else { return "No date" }
    return dateFormatterOutput.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: This is seriously error prone. You will have too many issues with this code.

Comment: Btw if can improve your configure method making a generic initializer that takes a predicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414890/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for your reply, but it's entirely useless unless you explain why

Comment: You are not setting the date formatter calendar. If the user device is using Buddhist calendar it will parse a date with 500+ years offset

Comment: Also not setting the calendar would result in failing to parse dates where there is no midnight if you pass a daylight savings transition date because the date string has no time. It will try to generate a midnight date but it doesn’t exist it so returns nil. If you set the calendar it will return the first date for that locale. Usually 1am.

Comment: Also when parsing fixed date format you should always set the locale to “en_US_POSIX”. This will avoid the date formatter reflecting the device locale and settings

Comment: Also be careful while parsing a date without timezone. The timezone you need to set the date formatter will depend on the context. If you are parsing a date of a bill to be paid it should use the timezone of the locale where the user has to pay it (fixed timezone). It could also be the timezone of the user (that’s how you have now) or the backend (server) or simply UTC timezone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865